# Is indexing a PyTorch tensor with a NumPy array legal?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

We can index a `Tensor` with another `Tensor` and **sometimes** we can successfully index a `Tensor` with a NumPy array. The following code works for some `dims`:

- `(2, 3)`
- `(2, 3, 2)`
- `(2, 3, 2, 2)`
- `(2, 100, 2, 2)`
- `(32, 100, 2, 2)`

but not for others:

- `(3, 3)`
- `(4, 3, 2)`
- `(5, 100, 2, 2)`

```py
import torch
def foo(dims):
    a = torch.zeros(dims)
    b = a.long()
    a[b] # always works
    a[b.numpy()] # sometimes works
```

If you try any of the examples from the second list you will get:

```
IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension (whatever dim is)
```

Is this a bug or should we rather say that NumPy was never meant to be an indexing object for `Tensor`s and hence we should consider it unexpected behaviour?

PyTorch versions 1.9.0 and 1.9.1.

Comment: suggestion: get rid of randomness

Comment: @bobcat random does nothting, `b.long()` is all zeros.

Comment: @QuangHoang ... unnecessary complexity

Comment: Simplified the demo code. Feel free to revert if this is wrong.

Comment: It seems like a peculiar find. You may want to submit a bug report.

Comment: It's also the case that `a[b]` and `a[b.numpy()]` do not give the same result whenever it works. Seems to be an instance where advanced indexing is behaving differently in the two situations.

Comment: Has been reported at https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/29522 and https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/34452, not sure what the status or decision on it is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71180403/16733101